# How To Make Use Of F2FS?

Tags: filesystem, f2fs

I am very interested in F2FS, so I installed `f2fs-tools` (File System For SSD/nand drives)

So my questions are:

- How do I use it?
- Is it safe to use?
- Can I format a USB drive with F2FS and again, would that be safe?

Comment: Thank you for editing my question, now it look nice ....@Oli

Comment: Apart from the problem with gparted, grub is unable to boot from a f2fs partition. I have installed ubuntu on ext4 and copied the root partition to a f2fs partition on the same device. update-grub recognizes the parition but throws an error "/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: unknown filesystem". Reinstalling grub and pointing to the root partition on f2fs does not work either as it says "Path `/media/user/new/boot/grub' is not readable by GRUB on boot. Installation is impossible. Aborting.", whereas /media/user/new/ is the mountpoint of the f2fs root parition. I would be very thankful if there is a

Answer (score 5):

I spent the day yesterday fiddling around with F2FS. Yes, you can format any partition with mkfs.f2fs in f2fs-tools. But neither the graphical nor the non-graphical installers will recognize it. So all you can do is use it as a data partition.

Since (g)parted regards it as an unformatted partition, they will successfully reformat it.

I'm eagerly awaiting the ability to try putting / on an F2FS partition, even if /boot has to remain ext4. Much of my testing is done with SDHC cards in netbooks.

Comment: parteds will see it now. encryption is still hazy.

Comment: Manjaro now allows you to manually format f2fs and install to it